# Convert List<double> to double[n,1]

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to convert a large List of length n into a double[n,1] array. What is the fastest way to make the conversion?

For further background this is to pass into an set Excel object's Range.Value which requires a two dimensional array.

Comment: What generates the list? What are you going to put in the second dimension of the array? What is "efficiency" (speed, memory consumption, other..) ?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly do you want to do.
inorder to convert List into array toy can use the ToArray method.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AviadHasidof - `.ToArray()` won't create a 2-D array.

Comment: Do you mean **2d** array? ` double[n,1]`

Comment: How are you defining "most efficient"? Smallest code? Fastest execution? Least memory usage? Least garbage generated?

Comment: I need it to be double[n,1] as I am using it to set an Excel Range.Value for a list of about 100,000 values.  So I can't do .ToArray() since this will not have the right dimensions.  I define most efficient as fastest.

Comment: Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Asking in a better way helps you to get the answer you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm writing this on the assumption that you *really* want the most efficient way to do this.  Extreme performance almost always comes with a trade-off, usually code readability.

I can still substantially optimize one part of this as the comments note, but I didn't want to go overboard using dynamic methods on first pass.

```
const int TEST_SIZE = 100 * 1000;
//Test data setup
var list = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++)
    list.Add(i);
//Grab the list's underlying array, which is not public
//This can be made MUCH faster with dynamic methods if you want me to optimize
var underlying = (double[])typeof(List<double>)
    .GetField("_items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(list);
//We need the actual length of the list because there can be extra space in the array
//Do NOT use "underlying.Length"
int underlyingLength = list.Count;
//Benchmark it
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var twodarray = new double[underlyingLength, 1];
Buffer.BlockCopy(underlying, 0, twodarray, 0, underlyingLength * sizeof(double));
var elapsed = sw.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed: {elapsed}");
```

Output:

> Elapsed: 00:00:00.0001998

Hardware used:

AMD Ryzen 7 3800X @ 3.9 Ghz
32 GB DDR4 3200 RAM

Comment: Yes, this looks the quickest way to do it.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

This operation will take no more than a few milliseconds even on a slow core. So why bother? How many times will you do this conversion? If millions of times, than try to find a better approach. But if you do this when the end-user presses a button...

Criticize the answer, but please providing metrics if about efficiency.

```
// Populate a List with 100.000 doubles
Random r = new Random();
List<double> dList = new List<double>();
int i = 0;
while (i++ < 100000) dList.Add(r.NextDouble());

// Convert to double[100000,1]
Stopwatch chrono = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// Conversion:
double[,] ddArray = new double[dList.Count, 1];
int dIndex = 0;
dList.ForEach((x) => ddArray[dIndex++, 0] = x);

Console.WriteLine("Completed in: {0}ms", chrono.Elapsed);
```

Outputs: (10 repetitions) - Maximum: 2.6 ms

```
Completed in: 00:00:00.0020677ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0026287ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0013854ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0010382ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0019168ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0011480ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0011172ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0013586ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0017165ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0010508ms
```

Edit 1.

```
double[,] ddArray = new double[dList.Count, 1];
foreach (double x in dList) ddArray[dIndex++, 0] = x;
```

seems just a little bit faster, but needs more testing:

```
Completed in: 00:00:00.0020318ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0019077ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0023162ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0015881ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0013692ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0022482ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0015960ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0012306ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0015039ms
Completed in: 00:00:00.0016553ms
```

Comment: What are the metrics on your end? I have i7-6500U 2.50 GHz, running Windows 8.1 Enterprise (x64)

Comment: Thanks, this was my default approach, but I somehow thought there might be a way to do this without a loop.  But you are right this is pretty quick so sometimes the easiest way is the best!

Comment: the metrics are almost half on my end. CPU is i7-6950x extreme edition. By the way for loop would even be faster than this. Just FYI

Comment: I've a for loop in the answer, as the first edit. It is not that faster (but the way I calculated is ..., no way to calculate it)

Comment: you dont have for loop for the first one. I tried both of them with 50 times in a loop. For loop was almost 30% faster than the avg spent time

Comment: You guys need to use specialized tool for benchmark, otherwise these results means nothing.

Comment: @apocalypse yes. As I also mentioned